# Using plotly to create an R plot that displays a title for each point when the mouse scrolls over it

Tags: r, plot, plotly

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465285/interactive-scatter-plots-in-r-overlay-hover-summary-tooltip-as-user-supplied-p) it seems like I should just be able to to put the variable name holding the plot into the ggplotly function and then the graph should have mouseover points. The data points do not display anything when I scroll the mouse over in adobe reader nothing displays. I would like to be able to write my own custom labels for each point.

```
install.packages(c("devtools"))
library(devtools)
dev_mode(on=T)
install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
install.packages(c("ggplot2"))
library(ggplot2)
install.packages(c("plotly"))   #Select mirror ("USA (WA)")
library("plotly")
install.packages(c("Cairo"))
library("Cairo")
all_rates = read.csv("file.txt")

for(i in unique(gsub('_[0-9]+', '', all_rates[,1]))){
        rates <- all_rates[grep(i, all_rates[,1]),]
        freq = unlist(rates[2])
        temp = unlist(rates[3])
        exn = unlist(rates[4])
        p = ggplot(rates, aes(freq,temp)) + geom_point(data=rates, aes(freq,temp,group=factor(exn),colour=factor(exn))) + geom_smooth(data=rates, aes(freq,temp,group=factor(exn),colour=factor(exn)),method = "lm",fill=NA)
        ggplotly(p)
        ggsave(paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

I still get

```
We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
```

As a warning. I was under the impression that I was using this version though based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository)

This is the output I get after all the checks and creates for the packages

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmpo0GRLE/downloaded_packages'
We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
Saving 7 x 7 in image
We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
Saving 7 x 7 in image
```

file.txt

```
clothing,freq,temp,exn
coat_1,0.3,10,1
coat_1,0.9,0,1
coat_1,0.1,20,1
coat_2,0.5,20,2
coat_2,0.3,15,2
coat_2,0.1,5,2
scarf,0.4,30,1
scarf,0.2,20,1
scarf,0.1,10,1
```

Comment: I think the problem is with you saving the graphs to pdf. You need html to have a mouse-over effect. If you just run through your code for, say, `i <-
 "coat"` then a browser windows opens up with information over all points.

Comment: Could you explain more please. `i <- "coat"` to the end of my code and it didn't change anything

Comment: If you drop your `for` loop, remove the line with `ggsave()`, and assign `i <- "coat"` before the loop then your code works since it shows the output as html in a browser. Pdf-files cannot be interactive

Comment: Theres no plots when I do that. I just get `The downloaded source packages are in
 '/tmp/RtmpMrEXX2/downloaded_packages'
We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`
Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')``